# How do I define static array in .cpp file of my class

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, static

I know there is many question talks about static function and variable but I can't find the one that explain me how do  things like this:

board.h

```
 class board:public QGraphicsPixmapItem 
{
public:
    board();
    static basedice *gamepos[8][8];
};
```

and I want to defined my array like this:

board.cpp

```
board::board()
{
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
        gamepos[i][j]=NULL;
        }
    }

}
```

And I have one more question,Is that a right way to use an array in many classes something like global array... for example in chess game for holding postion of my pieces? 
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I think you should look at this: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/811-static-member-variables/  it seems you don't understand well how static member of class work

Comment: I saw that before but I can't see how do I define it in cpp file

Comment: If you think about Chess, then every board has its own place to hold the Chess pieces -> it would probably make more sense to play a game of Chess per board and let every board own the place where the positions are stored (i.e. don't have static gamepos, instead make it a member of class board)

Comment: Why I shouldn't use static ,I think It's easier to use. Is there any problem in using static?

Comment: Because in your particular case, 1 board => 1 gamepos array.
If you make gamepos static then all the instances of board class share the same gamepos array.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios If any object of my board class use just one copy of gamepos,Isn't it easier to use?

Comment: @Félix Cantournet And I just want to use one gamepos! My question is that why I shouldn't use one gamepos? and how can I initialize my static array not just for chess example

Comment: I answered your question below. Static member isn't about anyuthing being easy. It is on the contrary about making everything a little harder to ENFORCE a particular constraint. make sure you actually need this.
The constraint in question is : I want there to be one and only one gamepos array, and it to be shared by all my Board instances.
And in this case there is 0 reason to reinitialize it everytime you create a Board. If you reinitialize the array everytime you create a board you get the same behavior as with a normal member, but you have to work harder for it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want the gamepos array to be static you can declare a static method in class Board that will initialize the array.

Then you call this method from outside the class.

```
int main() {

    Board * myboard = new Board();
    Board::initGamepos();

}
```

However looking at your code and what you want to do (which is reinitialize the gamepos array everytime you create a new Board instance, it is clear that you do NOT want gamepos to be static.
1 board <=> 1 gamepos array : that is not the mark of a static member, that is the mark of a standard member.

Comment: Oh.Sorry I use an wrong example.. I don't want to initialize it every time.. I shouldn't put that in constructor and I don't know why I didn't try it before...

Comment: Research "c++ singleton".  Perhaps you want to make the board a Singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are automatically initialized to zero/false/null, so you don't need to initialize the array.

Anyway, you should not be reinitializing a *static* variable from your *instance* constructor as that will produce funny results.

Comment: Isn't reinitialization an Oxymoron?

Comment: Ok but how can I initialize it?

Comment: You don't need to initialize it, it is by default initialized to NULL in your case.
If you want to initialize the static member to another value, you can make a static method to do so.

Comment: I have a question : Where is basedice declared, and where is it defined in this example, to me, it seems like basedice is not defined

Comment: @ user3670482 It's one of my classes that all of pieces inherits from it

Comment: It is not, but to be faire with the OP that is not the problem in question. The question stands with "int" in place of basedice.